# Erlang- Encoding function in my list comprehension doesn't seem to work?

Tags: list, function, erlang, list-comprehension

%% Function even_print(List),takes a list and returns a list of only even numbers. Function even_odd(X), takes an integer and tells  if it is even or odd.

```
 even_print(List) ->
           [X||X<-List, even<-even_odd(X)].
```

I don't understand why I get this error:

```
3> seq_erlang:even_print([2,3,4]).              
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    seq_erlang:'-even_print2/1-lc$^1/1-1-'(even) (seq_erlang.erl, line 154)
```

Just to comment, I have already implemented another function that prints even numbers just fine (so please don't comment with other implementations). I need help with this one only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be `even == even_odd(X)` instead of using `<-`.  A list comprehension has two types of "clauses": those that map over a list with `<-`, and those that filter out undesired combinations using a guard or boolean expression that doesn't contain `<-`.

(And a third one: extract bytes from a binary using `<=`; but that one is more rarely used.)